# Pyemma transition matrix returning array of unexpected size

Tags: python, markov-chains

I am using [pyemma](http://emma-project.org/latest/) to do some markov operations. Specifically I want to build a state transition matrix. In most cases pyemma is working correctly, however in some cases the transition matrix does not have the same number of states represented as there actually are in the data.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from pyemma import msm 

sequence = np.array([21, 21, 32 ,32 ,55 ,22 ,33 ,11 ,11 ,22 ,44 ,44 ,44 ,33 ,11 ,44 ,99])
vals = np.unique(sequence)
#note there are 8 unique states so we expect 8 by 8 transition matrix

model = msm.estimate_markov_model(sequence, 1)
transitionMatrix = model.transition_matrix
#transition matrix is 4 by 4
```

Why is the transition matrix not 8 by 8?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you estimate from data, PyEMMA will use the largest connected subset of states to do the estimation. The background is, that you can not give a unique measure for the transition matrix, when it is not connected, e.g. every state can be reached from any other state.

You can inspect which states are connected by looking at the resulting MSM object:

print(msm.active_set)

yields some integers corresponding to descrete state indices.